# How to identify which lines of code participated in a specific execution of a Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, code-coverage, trace

Suppose that I have a Java program within an IDE (Eclipse in this case).
Suppose now that I execute the program and at some point terminate it or it ends naturally.

Is there a **convenient** way to determine which lines executed at least once and which ones did not (e.g., exception handling or conditions that weren't reached?)

A manual way to collect this information would be to constantly step with the debugging and maintain a set of lines where we have passed at least once. However, is there some tool or profiler that already does that?

Edit: Just for clarification: I need to be able to access this information programmatically and not necessarily from a JUnit test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/) would be a good start: a code coverage tool would allow a coverage session to record the information you are looking for.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclemma.org](http://www.eclemma.org/images/smallscreen.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking about is called "coverage". There are several tools that measure that, some of which integrate into Eclipse. I've used [jcoverage](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/jcoverage-gpl) and it works (I believe it has a free trial period, after which you'd have to buy it). I've not used it, but you might also try [Coverlipse](http://coverlipse.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Doesn't coverage mean the union of the code that is affected by all unit tests in the system? 
I am looking for the result of a certain execution, not necessarily via JUnit. But I'll check it out. Thanks !

Comment: The term coverage is usually used with testing but it's the thing you are looking for. (The code coverage for a certain program execution)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you want more than the standard stacktrace data but you don't want to manually instrument your code with, say, log4j debug statements.

The only thing I can think of is to add some sort of bytecode tracing. Refer to [Instrumenting Java bytecode](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/pohjalai/k05/okk/seminar/Aarniala-instrumenting.pdf). The article references [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) which I haven't used but sounds like what you need...